# Convolution with the product of two delta function

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, dirac-delta

I don't know how to solve the following convolution problem:
$$[f(x)f^*(x+a)]\otimes_x[\delta(x)\delta(x-a)]$$
$*$ is complex conjugate and $\otimes$ stands for convolution. I only know some basic rules of convolution and Fourier transform, like
$$f(x)\otimes \delta(x-a)=f(x-a)$$
$$f(x)\delta(x-a)=f(a)\delta(x-a)$$
Could anyone give the process of solving the problem or tell me some rules that is necessary to solve it?

The whole formula is as follows:
$$G(x,y) = A(x)A^*(x+y)\otimes_x \{[\delta(x)+\phi(x)][\delta(x-y)+\phi^*(x-y)]\}=|A(x)|^2\delta(y)+A(x)A^*(x+y)\phi^*(-y)+A(x-y)A^*(x)\phi(y)$$
$\phi(x) << 1$
I think I know how to get the last two terms:
$$A(x)A^*(x+y)\otimes[\delta(x)\phi^*(x-y)] = A(x)A^*(x+y)\otimes[\delta(x)\phi^*(-y)] = A(x)A^*(x+y)\phi^*(-y)$$
$$A(x)A^*(x+y)\otimes[\delta(x-y)\phi(x)] = A(x)A^*(x+y)\otimes[\delta(x-y)\phi(y)] = A(x-y)A^*(x)\phi(y)$$
But how to get the first term?

Comment: $\delta(x)\delta(x-a)$ is the everywhere zero distribution, no? For $a\neq 0$

Comment: Why? I think $\inf \times 0$ is not defined.

Comment: I don't have a simple answer. The (singular) supports are disjoint, see http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/dang/JPA-14.pdf

Comment: Thank you all the same.

Comment: At the very least, I think you should ask whoever gave you this problem for the meaning of $\delta(x) \delta(x-a)$, which you clearly need to understand fully before you can compute its convolution with something else

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice. I extract the problem from a big problem, perhaps I should put the whole equation here. I will edit my question.

Comment: I have post the full problem.